# Cannot get PowerShell to give an exact match with Select-String (or anything else)

Tags: powershell

I have a file called `1.xml` which contains the following text:

```
Test.wav
"Test2.wav"
```

When I execute the following PowerShell command

```
Select-String -Path "1.xml" -Pattern "t.wav" -SimpleMatch
```

It always gives me a match! I don't want a match! "t.wav" is obviously not in `1.xml`!

I thought `-SimpleMatch` is supposed to give an exact match. I've tried all sorts of other variations, including `Get-Content` and `Contains`, but nothing helps.

Comment: According to the text you provided, the pattern "t.wav" is indeed in your string, as is "2.wav".  If you changed your pattern to "e.wav", you won't return a string.

Comment: "*"t.wav" is obviously not in 1.xml!*" - yes it is; tes**T.WAV**. Exactly what to change to do what you want, depends on you describing what you want; `-pattern "^t.wav$"` will match an entire line..

Comment: OMG. You guys are right! My eyes were crossing looking at this. Haha.

Comment: Using PowerShell, I basically want to search an xml file for a list of file names and get exact matches. I might generate a list of names from the xml file and ensure each file name is on one line. Then, hopefully I can use that entire line match.

Comment: No worries.  Happy to help.

Comment: Your input file here is not XML; if you have XML and the structure matters, `Select-XML` might be more appropriate than `Select-String`. Otherwise you will get exact matches with what you're doing now, or you will need to regex escape the filenames, or you will need  to add XML-aware regex syntax to handle XML quotes or angle brackets or CDATA.. depending on what input you have and what output you want...

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Yes - agree the file here is not XML. I was trying to be concise in my post. I am going to look at Select-XML, as that might be better for what I am doing.